# How can I add text to each "section" of the navigation bar? For Home x text shows, for History: y text shows?

Tags: html, css

so I'm working on a project where I'm supposed to create a website and also talk about internet history & the effect it has had on society. Anyways, my plan or idea was to make 3 individual sections to the webpage. "Home" being Home of the website, just showing image/background and "hello to my assignment", then "history" tab has some text about the history of internet etc, and then the effect on society being the third tab with a text on how it actually has affected society.

Anyways. if you take whatever background, do as I have here you can see I have three current tabs on the right side of the website. I don't know how to add text individually to each one and when you click the next, X text disappears and Y text arrives next to that ones name. How can I do this?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  /* standard font "vikt" bold/italic etc eller nummer som 400*/
}

.background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(../css/qwx.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* spelar bara bakgrunden en gång och inte repeterad igen */
  background-size: cover;
  /* "cover" för att täcka hela "elementet" alltså bakgrunden */
  position: relative;
  /* position relativ gör så att den positioneras relativ till sin "originella" position. */
}

.rad {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  /* istället för "100% elr 80%" eller liknande så är den automatisk för att vara mer "flexibel" */
  position: absolute;
  /*används för att positionera "relativt" med sin närmaste positionerade "parent" */
  left: 0%;
  /* 0% för vill ha den i vänstra hörnet */
  top: 30%;
  /* vill ha i mitten ish o för mig såg det bra ut iaf (vet inte om detta ändras beroende på upplösning eller liknande, har ej provat */
}

.rad a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Tahoma", "Comic Sans MS";
  /* två "fonts" ifall den första inte finns/laddas in */
  font-weight: 600;
  /* tjockleck */
  height: 80px;
  margin: 3px 0;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  /* center för att stoppa texten i mitten av rutan */
  /*-- inlineblock används för att få bredden & höjden att respekteras, samt padding/margin */
  transition: 400ms;
  /* lite längre tid för att knapparna ska registreras som att dom är pekade på, blir en fin liten effekt */
}

a.active,
.rad a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  /* vill ha det så att när man häver över muspekarn så blir rad a 100% bredd, medans när rad a, b, c, är inaktiva och inte har muspekaren över är mindre */
}

.a {
  width: 90%;
}

.b {
  width: 80%;
}

.c {
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="rad">
    <a class="a active" href="#">Startsida</a>
    <a class="b" href="#">Historia</a>
    <a class="c" href="#">Påverkan</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to accomplish.  Do you need 3 separate html pages? Or one page with 3 sections that scroll into view when you click a tab?

Comment: I don't know, but simplest I can explain is say you go onto Ebay. There's a link called "products" with Text, and then you click "Sales" and you get a new "page" with sales on. Basically I want "Home page" to have X text, and when I click page "History" there's new text that describes the history instead and X text from "Homepage" is now overwritten or "hidden" , and changes back when I want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What follows utilizes Bootstrap and JQuery to create a very simple version of what you are describing, but I'm guessing probably not what you need.

It is however an excellent example of how far internet programming has come since its modest beginning.

Some html markup and some user provided content and here you have a simple "3 page" website

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-Startsida">Startsida</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-Historia">Historia</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-Påverkan">Påverkan</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-Startsida">
          <div class="float-left mt-1 ml-1 mr-3 mb-3">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
          </div>
          <span>Startsida</span>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-Historia">Historia</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-Påverkan">Påverkan</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! It works how I wanted it too, I really appreciate your help!